October 2024 Photo Competition: Leaves
The topic is "leaves", so photos containing leaves of any kind (on a tree, on the ground, etc.).
The contest will end at the end of October (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and suitable for work.
If you have people recognizable in the photo, you must either (a) have their permission to post the photo or (b) make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics. Also, you can join us in chat to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.



Ginkgo leaves filling the spaces between paver stones on a walking path.  Photo taken in Seoul during the autumn of 2018.

This photo had the most upvotes at the end of the month, so congratulations!

Scotland in October - reds and greens.
As most deciduous trees in Scotland turn brown and then fall, I always like to see a flash of red.
A dog wood in my garden, Oct 2021

Lovely contrasts on Stirling University's campus in Oct 2020

Near Stobo Castle in 2009


I really like #2, it's in my desktop wallpaper rotation now!

Indeed, picture 2 very beautiful!! @MackM

thank you! It's on the north east side of the University of Stirling campus. At this time of year it is stunning.

Possibly the most debated leaf of all times, cannabis leaf!
Now legal in Malta and Gozo, where I took this photo in July this year. Let me remark that also the amount of this veggie that was in that house on that day was within the limit according to the local law.


I took this photo of some fall leaves when I was going on a walk. This would have been October/November of 2022 in Washington, USA.


Château de Versailles' gardens in Autumn
The first two pictures below show a vast amount of colorful leaves that could be found in Château de Versailles' gardens in the Autumn of 2012 (some day in November). The first one seems to be a zoom of the second one.
I can see green, yellow, pink and orange leaves! Anyone see any red ones, perhaps?
About the third picture, I like the (almost) symmetric shape of the tall trees pointing at the horizon besides the Grand Canal de Versailles. Lots of leaves on the ground as well as on the trees.




Just me hiding behind a gigantic leaf :)
Photo taken by my friend.
Somewhere in the Amazon
November 2017


The Highlands and Urquhart Castle, Scotland
During a drive from Edinburgh to Inverness, in November 2012, I had to take occasional breaks, not because I was confused driving on the English side of the road for the first time, but 'cause I was astonished looking at the beauty of the Highlands with it's countless mountains as can be seen on the first picture below. Lots of colored leaves can be seen on the trees.
The Loch (lake) Ness home of the famous Nessie can be seen from the Urquhart Castle on the second picture of this post as well as a patch of green and yellow (and some other colors) leaves.
The third and final picture is related to the second one, showing a little bit of the ruins of the castle as well as plenty of grass leaves on the foreground.




Congratulations on winning the virtual prize this month!

@cocomac Wow! I thought the most upvoted post would be the winner! Thanks for giving me the virtual bragging rights for October!

To go with @jcklopp's photo, ginkgo leaves still on the tree, Beverwijk, the Netherlands, where the tree is an exotic species and quite rare. The tree stood out as bright yellow-green rather than dull brown-green as most.
Photos taken 4 October 2024


